# How to get a linux command output to chef attribute

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

I want to get a command output into a chef attribute. Can some one help me how to set that in execute resource or bash resource.

```
ruby_block "something" do
    block do
        #tricky way to load this Chef::Mixin::ShellOut utilities
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)      
        command = 'cat #{fileName}'
        command_out = shell_out(command)
        node.set['my_attribute'] = command_out.stdout
    end
    action :create
end
```

How to use attributes in the above code..

Comment: please add some code so we can see the problem you're facing

Comment: Seems like a question for https://serverfault.com/, yet still not clear what you want.

Comment: The actual problem seems to be `command = 'cat #{fileName}'` where @SASI should have used double quotes to enable parsing (ie. `command = "cat #{fileName}"`)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to your question is pretty mich given in [How can I put the output of a Chef 'execute resource' into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309808/how-can-i-put-the-output-of-a-chef-execute-resource-into-a-variable). With tiny modification, if I understand the question right, your problem can be solved like this:

```
ruby_block "something" do
    block do
        #tricky way to load this Chef::Mixin::ShellOut utilities
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)      
        command = 'cat /etc/hostname'
        command_out = shell_out(command)
        node.set['my_attribute'] = command_out.stdout
    end
    action :create
end
```

Replace the content of `command` with the command that you want to run and `my_attribute` with the attribute that you want to set.

Comment: This IMHO at least answers your question. If you describe your problem, we might find a way more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks StephenKing.. 

my command is 

"sudo su - grid
+ASM
asmcmd lsdsk -G data"

I have to login as grid user and enter into +ASM process and run the command. Can you please help me how to run that in recipe.

Comment: @user3886612 Edit your question to describe the use case, so we can cast a re-open vote

Comment: @SASI repeating yourself in comments won't help. there's an edit button under your question to update it.

Comment: It would be also interesting to see, in what way you have to use that information later.

Comment: What does         Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)      
 do in this?

Comment: This makes the functions of `Chef::Mixin::ShellOut` available within the `ruby_block`.

Comment: There is deprecation warning for using `node.set`, that is being replaced with `node.default`, ref: https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_attributes.html, I used same solution except changing `node.set` as per deprecation warning.