# How to get the version of chef-client running on windows node using knife search query

Tags: chef-infra

How to get the version of chef-client running on windows node using knife search query ?. For example for linux nodes it is very easy as below will get the desired results.

```sh
knife search node "name:xyz" -a name -a ipaddress -a os -a platform -a platform_family -a packages.**chef** -c knife.rb
```

Is there a similar way for windows nodes ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mr. : That will be a time consuming activity and also  credentials are required. However i found another way of doing it i.e run knife search as below. And filter the results for the required package.

```sh
knife search node "name:<name>" -a name -a ipaddress  -a packages  -c knife.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

List all endpoints' chef client version:

```sh
knife node list | xargs -n 1 knife node show -a chef_packages.chef.version
```

List a single endpoint chef client version:

```sh
knife node show nodename -a chef_packages.chef.version
```

Answer (score 0):

get the chef-client version by execute [`chef-client --version`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client/#options) over [ssh](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_ssh/). something like:

```
knife ssh "name:xyz" "chef-client -v" -a name
```

another way, it to store the chef-client version as a [node attribute](https://docs.chef.io/attributes/) and then retrive it via [search](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_search/)

```rb
node.default['chef-client']['version'] = Gem.loaded_specs['chef'].version
```

or by running [`chef-client -v`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721981) and storing it as a node attribute.

you might be also interested in [chef-client updater](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef_client_updater/blob/master/providers/default.rb#L123)

Comment: There is already a node attribute that has the version: chef_packages.chef.version

Comment: @DracoAter: does it hold for chef-client in local mode when using chef rubygem?

Comment: I believe so, but I haven't tried. It least it works in test kitchen with chef-zero.

Comment: @DracoAter: kitchen with chef-zero is running using chef binary package and not a  rubygem