# Unable to set the node attributes within a ruby block

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, ruby-block

I have exactly the same code as suggested in the given link by @StephenKing (https://stackoverflow.com/users/400222/stephenking) and although the command works and gives the correct return value (verified using log/print) the value is not set in the attribute. Did something significantly change over the years? [How to get a linux command output to chef attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721575/how-to-get-a-linux-command-output-to-chef-attribute/29721981#29721981)

```rb
ruby_block "something" do
    block do
        #tricky way to load this Chef::Mixin::ShellOut utilities
        Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)      
        command = 'cat /etc/hostname'
        command_out = shell_out(command)
        node.default['my_attribute'] = command_out.stdout
    end
    action :create
end
```

**Note**: I also tried with `node.force_default` to set the value and that didn't set the value either.