# In chef how to catch execute resource's command output in variable?

Tags: chef-infra, aws-opsworks, ohai-gem

I want to use private ip address later in my Chef recipe for that how can I catch it in a variable. My code looks like...

```
execute 'privateip' do
command 'curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4'
action :run
end
```

I want to catch the output of curl command in a variable something like..

```
privip = 'curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4'
```

and then use that value in configuration file OR is there any way to get the private ipaddresses of aws instance, because ohai doesn't support the `privateip` attribute. Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put the output of a Chef 'execute resource' into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309808/how-can-i-put-the-output-of-a-chef-execute-resource-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `local-ipv4` value in the `node['ec2']['local_ipv4']` attribute. IIRC all the EC2 *meta-data* is included under `node['ec2']`.

If you still prefer to run a command, you can use the `shell_out!` helper:

```ruby
output = shell_out!('mycommand --some --arguments').stdout
```

As they said in the comments, for this particular case you can also use the `Chef::HTTP` class:

```ruby
http = Chef::HTTP.new('http://169.254.169.254')
privip = http.get('/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4')
```

Comment: Why not use ruby's HTTP libraries directly?

Comment: So a few levels of "don't actually do this". First, as mentioned, you should use `Chef::HTTP` for HTTP requests. Second, you should always use the `shell_out!` wrapper when possible. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The only limitation of using `shell_out!` is that it does not work with Chef 11. You need Chef 12. But it looks much simpler. Of course, in this particular case, it is better to use the HTTP libraries if you know how. Thanks Noah!

Comment: Thanks...I will try this in my recipe.