# What is the chef appropriate way to ensure idempotency when an execute block's "creates" value is not fully known?

Tags: chef-infra

Within the following code's `creates` directive, the specified value contains a (actually, more than one) wildcard.

```
execute "Install Vagrant plugin: #{plugin}" do
   environment ({ 'HOME' => ::Dir.home(user), 'USER' => user })
   command "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}"
   creates "/home/#{user}/.vagrant.d/gems/*/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-*"
end
```

I expect that there is not a chef intended method of handling a situation where only a directory *pattern* is known beforehand and not the actual *full path*. The Chef documentation for execute does not explicitly say whether or not `creates` will pattern match, but after testing, I believe it does not and is not intended to pattern match.

This being the case, would the above be an appropriate use for Chef::Mixin::ShellOut? Or would there be another more chef intended method?

If the former, I'm anticipating using examples from stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721575/how-to-get-a-linux-command-output-to-chef-attribute), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309808/how-can-i-put-the-output-of-a-chef-execute-resource-into-a-variable)) to determine whether a directory exists matching a pattern resembling the value of the `creates` directive above and using that return value to set whether or not to run the execute block in question.

Any tips, hints, or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

- Informatician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `not_if` or `only_if` guard clause. The `creates` property is just a helper for `not_if { ::File.exist?(the_path) }`. In this case what you probably want is either `not_if "vagrant plugin list | grep #{plugin}"` or the slightly cleaner (IMO) `not_if { shell_out!('vagrant plugin list').stdout.include?(plugin) }`.

Comment: This is great, again very valuable feedback. The first part of the answer (`creates` being a helper for `not_if` and use of `not_if` or `only_if`) was definitely what I needed. Providing both a simple and cleaner method for the particular task at hand though is above and beyond. Very much appreciated, thanks coderanger!